# How to compile an Informix GLS Locale/Character Set. (.lc file into .lco to make an Informix locale for databases)

Tags: character-encoding, environment-variables, instance, informix, character-set

Overview:

I am trying to make my own GLS locale/character set. I am doing this to add it to the locales in my informix instance under `GLS/lc11/en_us/myfile.lco` so that I can set my database/db locales to the locale I just created.

Details:

1. I am creating a `.lc` file for the GLS locale/character set. However, I cannot find how to compile that `.lc` file into a `.lco` file. How do I compile a `.lc` file into a `.lco` file.
2. I am also looking for some more examples of `.lc` files to base mine off of. Does any one know where I could find some examples. I know that in the informix instance they are stored in the folder `$INFORMIXDIR/GLS/lc11/os/`.

If this is not the way you create a `.lco` GLS character set in Informix. What would be the correct steps? Also am I missing any steps?

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. The GLS compiler is not externally available (pretty sure it never was). Playing with locales files (in particular codeset definitions) could be quite harmful for a IDS instance. 

May I ask what are you trying to achieve? .lc files are only used for collating purposes (order/currency/etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I will put this as an answer because it's way to big to put it as a comment, technically speaking, the answer to this question should be: "you can't, there is no Informix GLS compiler available for external use" )

Looking at your previous question, I guess what you want, is a way to filter for ascii characters.
Even if you could , I wouldn't go the route of writing your own gls definition, it's not as simple as it sounds.

There is a plain ASCII locale with Informix:

```
d:\infx\ids12\gls\cm3>grep ASCII registry
#         ASCII characters (except that a code-set name cannot begin with
#         The code-set number consists of 1 or more decimal ASCII digits
ASCII           364     # 0x016c

d:\infx\ids12\gls\cm3>
```

Only some languages have it (like German or Spanish):

```
d:\infx\ids12\gls\cm3>dir ..\..\016c.* /s
 Volume in drive D is Data750
 Volume Serial Number is F0B7-2E46

 Directory of d:\infx\ids12\gls\cm3

21/01/2017  20:23             6,408 016c.cmo
               1 File(s)          6,408 bytes

 Directory of d:\infx\ids12\gls\lc11\de_de

21/01/2017  20:25             4,369 016c.lco
               1 File(s)          4,369 bytes


 Directory of d:\infx\ids12\gls\lc11\es_es

21/01/2017  20:25             4,611 016c.lco
               1 File(s)          4,611 bytes
```

but nothing stop you for copying the locale file (.lco) to the 'en_us' directory and use it (of course, only for testing purposes).

```
d:\infx\ids12\gls\cm3>cp d:\infx\ids12\gls\lc11\de_de\016c.lco d:\infx\ids12\gls\lc11\en_us

d:\infx\ids12\gls\cm3>

d:\infx\ids12\gls\cm3>dir d:\infx\ids12\gls\lc11\en_us
 Volume in drive D is Data750
 Volume Serial Number is F0B7-2E46

 Directory of d:\infx\ids12\gls\lc11\en_us

09/03/2018  11:07    <DIR>          .
09/03/2018  11:07    <DIR>          ..
09/03/2018  11:07             4,369 016c.lco
21/01/2017  20:25             2,666 0333.lco
21/01/2017  20:25             7,578 0333dict.lco
21/01/2017  20:25             4,071 0333dres.lco
21/01/2017  20:25             4,096 0333extn.lco
21/01/2017  20:25             4,412 0352.lco
21/01/2017  20:25             7,955 0352dict.lco
21/01/2017  20:25             4,410 04e4.lco
21/01/2017  20:25             7,824 04e4dict.lco
21/01/2017  20:25             7,818 04e4edic.lco
21/01/2017  20:25             4,410 04e4euro.lco
21/01/2017  20:25            63,649 e005.lco
21/01/2017  20:25            85,484 e01c.lco
21/01/2017  20:25             2,668 e02f.lco
21/01/2017  20:25             7,815 e02fdict.lco
21/01/2017  20:25            64,886 e030.lco
              16 File(s)        284,111 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  234,801,618,944 bytes free

d:\infx\ids12\gls\cm3>
```

After that you should be able to create a database with a the "en_US.ascii" locale:

```
D:\infx\ids12>set DB_LOCALE=en_US.ascii

D:\infx\ids12>set CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.1252

D:\infx\ids12>dbaccess - -
> create database enusascii with log;

Database created.

> select * from sysmaster:sysdbslocale where dbs_dbsname='enusascii';

dbs_dbsname  enusascii
dbs_collate  en_US.364

1 row(s) retrieved.

>
```

If you try to insert anything greater than 0x7F it should complaint:

```
D:\infx\ids12>od -t x1 test_ascii.unl
0000000000    74  D6  73  74  7C  0D  0A
0000000007

D:\infx\ids12>cat test_ascii.unl
t€st|

D:\infx\ids12>

....
Database created.

> create table t1(c1 char(10));

Table created.

> load from test_ascii.unl insert into t1;

23103: Code-set conversion function failed due to illegal sequence or invalid value.

  847: Error in load file row 1.
Error in line 1
Near character position 40
>
```

Same file can be loaded in a 819 database:

```
D:\infx\ids12>set | grep LOCALE
CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.1252
DB_LOCALE=en_US.819

D:\infx\ids12>dbaccess enus819 -

Database selected.

> load from test_ascii.unl insert into t1;

1 row(s) loaded.

>
```

You get a 23103 because the GLS conversion function detects an invalid mapping for the 0xD6 value ('Ö').
The conversion file between 1252 and ASCII is shows that anything greather than 0x7F will throw an error.

```
<source_version>        2
<modified_date>     "05-04-2004"
<source_codeset>      "Windows Code Page 1252"
<target_codeset>      "ASCII 7-Bit"

# Conversion Table
\x00...\xff \x00... #  Default everything onto itself
\x80    \x7f error  #  euro-sign
\x82    \x7f error  #  single low-9 quotation mark 
\x83    \x7f error  #  dutch guilder sign (ibm437 159) 
....    same.....
....
\xfd    \x7f error  #  latin small letter y with acute 
\xfe    \x7f error  #  latin small letter thorn (icelandic) 
\xff    \x7f error  #  latin small letter y with diaeresis
```

Remember, you will only get an error if there is a conversion between codesets. If your CLIENT_LOCALE is the same as your DB_LOCALE, nobody is going to 'filter/validate' your data as you are telling the client that there is no need for a conversion.

Comment: Thank you for shedding more light on the situation.